# comment plugin doesn't work well on safari

Tags: php, facebook, plugins, safari, facebook-comments

facebook comment plugin doesn't works good on Safari browser, it appears to the side and can't see it within the tab. Anyone know? Know how to fix it?

Its work but appears to the left side even I set to right, then in the tab do not see the comment plugin. It happens only in the Safari browser

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=*****";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <img src="image.jpg"/><br/>

   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="the link..." data-num-posts="5" data-width="800" align="right"></div>
```

It is important to note that it works well in all other browsers
thank's

Comment: Without test page / codes, we can't really help.

Comment: hi, i edit the first post, include the codes.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work ok for me in Safari 5.1.5. I wouldn't try adding `align` as an attribute of the fb plugin element.

Try something like this:

```
<div align="right">
  <div class="fb-comments" data-href="the link..." data-num-posts="5" data-width="800"></div>
</div>
```

You may have more complicated HTML than what you have included in your question, so maybe post a screenshot and more of the HTML.

Comment: I would suggest using CSS instead of `align` attribute in modern HTML codes. use `style="float: right;"` instead.